# Deviance and Score Residual plots

Tags: r, plot, cox-regression

I'm trying to plot the Deviance and Score residual plots on the data(kidtran) for Proportional hazard model.
1- I've attempted to plot the Deviance Residual plot for coxph model with the covariates (race , gender and gender by race interaction) using the following code:

```
library(KMsurv)
data(kidtran)
kidtran

####Deviance Residuals####
fit<-coxph(Surv(time, delta)~race+gender+race*gender, method="breslow", data=kidtran)
resid.dev<-resid(fit,type="deviance")
par(mfrow = C(1,1))
plot(resid.dev,xlab = "Risk Score", ylab = "Deviance Residual", lwd=1 )
title("Deviance Residual")
resid.dev
abline(h=2.5, col="blue")
abline(h=-2.5, col="blue")
```

It should look like this:
[image]

This was the results I got.
[image]

In addition to the message error after running

```
par(mfrow = C(1,1))
```

Error in C(1, 1) : object not interpretable as a factor

2- I did plot a Score residual plot for each covariate:

```
##score for interaction
fit<-coxph(Surv(time, delta)~race+gender+race*gender, method="breslow", data=kidtran)
resid.score<-resid(fit,type="score")
par(mfrow = C(1,2))
plot(resid.score)
resid.score
abline(h=2.5, col="blue")
abline(h=-2.5, col="blue")

##score for race
fit1<-coxph(Surv(time, delta)~race, method="breslow", data=kidtran)
resid.score<-resid(fit1,type="score")
par(mfrow = C(1,2))
plot(resid.score)
resid.score
abline(h=2.5, col="blue")
abline(h=-2.5, col="blue")

##score for gender
fit2<-coxph(Surv(time, delta)~gender, method="breslow", data=kidtran)
resid.score<-resid(fit2,type="score")
par(mfrow = C(1,2))
plot(resid.score)
resid.score
abline(h=2.5, col="blue")
abline(h=-2.5, col="blue")
```

The results should look as:
[image]

[image]
[image]

I got different results. Is the problem from the code I'm using for the plots or from the coxph code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the risk score should be the prediction (hazard ratio if I remember my statistics correctly?), in the code you have above, the residuals is only a vector, so :

```
##note it's a small c for par
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(predict(fit),resid.dev,xlab = "Risk Score", 
ylab = "Deviance Residual", lwd=1 ,main="Deviance Residual")
abline(h=2.5, col="blue")
abline(h=-2.5, col="blue")
```

[image]

For the second plot, you need to plot the number of observation on the x-axis:

```
fit<-coxph(Surv(time, delta)~race+gender+race*gender, method="breslow",data=kidtran)
resid.score<-resid(fit,type="score")
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
for(i in colnames(resid.score))
plot(1:nrow(resid.score),resid.score[,i],main=i,xlab="obs no")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. How can I draw lines for the last 3 graphs?

Comment: try adding type="l" like inside the plot(...type="l")

Comment: if you join the dots it is like that; ```for(i in colnames(resid.score)){plot(1:nrow(resid.score),resid.score[,i],main=i,xlab="obs no",type="l")}```

Comment: because sometimes you have residues that are lower / higher than expected, thats why it looks weird